# Need to create a cluster(L , A , B) , that returns sub-lists of L on A and B respectively , based on a condition

Tags: prolog

Let's say we have the list L = [ 1,  5 , 32 , 5 , 7, 8] 
I need to create a cluster( L , A ,B ) which divides L in 2 sub-lists ( A , B).
A is supposed to contain all the values that appear on list L BEFORE the value 32 . 
B is supposed to contain all the values that appear on list L AFTER the value 32.
32 is supposed to be excluded from both lists.

```
?- cluster([11 , 18 , 9 , 32 , 13 , 12 ] , A , B).
A = [11 , 18 , 9], B = [13 ,12].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for the operation you wanted :

```
cluster([L|Rest],[L|A],B) :-
   L \= 32,
   cluster(Rest,A,B).

cluster([L|Rest],[],Rest):-
   L == 32.
```

What this code does, it iterates over the list and adds the values to A until it reaches the first **32** value, then assigns the rest of the list directly to B.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
cluster(L, Break, A,B) :-
    append(A, [Break|B], L).
```

For example

```
? cluster([11 , 18 , 9 , 32 , 13 , 12 ] , 32, A , B).
A = [11, 18, 9],
B = [13, 12] ;
false.
```